# Other appsare terminated when I try to copy an auth code from the Google Authenticator

Tags: google-authenticator

I have the Google Authenticator app and I want to log into Stack Overflow with my Google account.

But if I leave the login page from app to look at the authenticator code, the SO application refreshes.

It can't use an application specific password. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an app specific passphrase. Stackexchange uses Google as an OpenID provider and that works with access tokens.

To continue/finish the OpenID process you need to be logged in to Google of course (using the regular 2-step passphrase+token method). You will then be asked if you want to grant access by Google and the app will get an access token.

Comment: I am asking how to run [stackoverflow app][1] and [authenticator][2] at the same time on my android phone.


  [1]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burmat.stack.overflow.web.app&feature=search_result
  [2]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&feature=search_result

Comment: Just copy an authenticator code in advance. The validity time span should be long enough to do that.

Comment: In other words, attempt to login from the app, enter the Google account username/password. When asked for the verification code, press home, the open up authenticator, long press on the code and select copy to clipboard. Now press home again and go back to the Stack Overflow app. select the text field, long press, and select paste.

Comment: I think that Google is used as *"OAuth2"* provider, not OpenID.

Answer (score 1):

You can successfully reopen the Stack Exchange in the state of asking for Google account's code of authentication, if:

- Open Authenticator, and memorize/copy..., the 6 digit number.
- Open the **App Drawer** *(not the recent used list access by pushing home button for a while!)*
- Select the internet browser from there.
- Now you should have the browser in the state you left it *(waiting for the 6 digit number)*

Although this is a solution to ***(Not being able to introduce the 6 digit code)***, it won't solve the problem of Stack Exchange app inability to save your login credentials.